# Como dar acabamento em layout de App Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Como é feito para personalizar o layout de uma aplicação Android. Tenho visto Apps tão bem acabadas e queria aprender a dar tal refinamento para meus Apps.

O App [Toshi Finance](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thirdframestudios.android.expensoor) é um bom exemplo do que eu estou falando.

Comment: Tem algo mais específico que você queira saber? Na forma atual, esta pergunta não conseguirá respostas reais. Só uma lista de ideias, que não é o que desejamos em um site de **perguntas** e **respostas**: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na parte do código, para personalizar um layout ou widget troca-se o drawable dos backgrounds por outro com imagens trocadas.

Como por exemplo, em um **EditText** você pode trocar o background (tanto no xml quanto no código) por um com bordas arredondadas (no estado com ou sem foco) e este ficará parecido com o da app que você passou como referência. Da mesma forma foi feito com os botões, os toggles desta app.

Se, por exemplo, você quiser aplicar as mudanças em todos os botões do app é só criar um Theme para seu app para alterar o background de todos os botões.

**No XML do Layout**

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/meu_edittext_customizado"/>
```

**No Drawable meu_edittext_customizado.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/meu_edittext_default" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/meu_edittext_desativado" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/meu_edittext_ativado" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/meu_edittext_com_foco" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/meu_edittext_default" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/meu_edittext_desativado_com_foco" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/meu_edittext_desativado" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Alexandre era o que eu queria saber.

Answer (score 0):

- Etapa 1:

Para aplicativos móveis a parte de `Layout` tem seu principio no [UX Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design): A parte em que se define a experiência que se espera ter quando o usuário usa o aplicativo.

- Etapa 2:

Posterior a isso aplicamos o [UI Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface_design): A parte que se aplica a experiência definida no UX Design através de componentes visíveis como botões, tabelas, animações etc.

**Cuidado para não confundir: [UX x UI](http://design.blog.br/web-design/ux-e-ui-design-qual-a-diferenca)**

- Etapa 3:

A parte de programação é importante na hora de se `construir` o aplicativo que foi desenhado e definido nas etapas anteriores, pois se o programador não conseguir faze-lo terá sido em vão todo esforço anterior.

---

**Edit:** No site do desenvolvedor `Android` mostra os [princípios de design focado na plataforma.](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html)

---

*Como a questão sem si não traz uma dúvida relacionada a programação, não tem como responder dando exemplos de códigos, bibliotecas etc*